# SQL insert some data

Tags: sql-insert, sql-server-2014

I need to insert data values into only some of my tables and can't find what the proper syntax should be. Here's the table for reference:

```
create table PERFORMER (
    STAGE_NM char(15) primary key,
    P_NAME varchar(10),
    CHRIST_NM varchar(10)
);
```

Lets say I only want to insert data into `STAGE_NM` and `P_NAME`, would I go about it like this:

```
insert data PERFORMER values ('The Cage', 'Nicolas Cage')
```

Or would I have empty `''` for the `CHRIST_NM` that I want to leave empty? Like this:

```
insert data PERFORMER values ('The Cage', 'Nicolas Cage', '')
```

I feel like it would be the first one, but I can't find anything saying that I'm right or wrong in this assumption.

Comment: Insert into table (column,...) Values (value1,...) ??

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server, which is it?

Comment: Sorry it autocorrected, I'll fix the tag. I'm in SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just be explicit in your insert statement?

```
insert performer (STAGE_NM, P_NAME) values ('The Cage', 'Nicolas Cage');
```

Comment: I considered that, but again wasn't sure if that's okay to do in this situation. I should have mentioned that I'm still quite new to the language. Any sort of notes I have from my professor doesn't say to use an explicit column unless you're creating it for the first time.

Comment: In the real world, use explicit columns whenever you can.  You don't know if you are the one who will have to fix it 2 years from now when someone added a new column to the table!  :)  It's also much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

You can add some column names if you don't want to insert data in all columns

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

So you can use

```
INSERT INTO Performer (STAGE_NM, P_NAME) VALUES ('The Cage', 'Nicolas Cage');
```

Hope it was helpful !

Bertrand

Answer (score 2):

It's highly recommended to use a list of columns, just in case you reorder the columns later, especially since they're all strings.

```
insert into table (stage_nm, p_name) 
values('The Cage', 'Nicolas Cage');
```

If you *really* don't want to list them and just have the values, I would recommend using NULL instead of a zero-length string, as in your example.